# Rspec test or-like (||=) operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, mocking, rspec

I'm wondering is there a way to test an expression like:

```
var[:test] ||= "value"
```

using Rspec. Basically I'd like to be able to specify something like:

```
var = mock
var.should_receive(:[]||=).with(:test)
```

To be more precise, I want to test that the `||=` is applied to the var[:test].

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The construct `var[:test] ||= value` essentially means:

```
if there is a key :test in hash
   var[:test] should remain what it is
else
   var[:test] = value
```

This means you have two tests on your hands, something along the lines of:

```
it "should not override var[:test]"
it "should set var[:test] to be equal to 'value'"
```

For example, lets say you have a class:

```
class Blah
  attr_reader :var
  def initialize(var={})
    @var=var
  end
  def set_test_key(value)
    var[:test] ||= "value"
  end
end
```

You can do something like:

```
describe Blah do
  it "should not override var[:test]" do
    blah = Blah.new({:test=>"foo"})
    blah.set_test_key("bar")
    blah.should equal("foo")
  end
  it "should set var[:test] to be equal to 'bar'" do
    blah = Blah.new
    blah.set_test_key("bar")
    blah.should equal("bar")
  end
end
```

That's the gist of it, will need to be adapted to your situation.

Comment: Very clean and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a `:[]||=` operator.

```
var[:test] ||= value
```

is simply a shorthand for

```
var[:test] = var[:test] || value
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about mocks, but assuming the code is inside a method:

```
def value
  @value ||= "value"
end
```

you could simply call it twice and check that both objects are the same:

```
it "should memoize the value" do
  value.should equal(value)
end
```